# Convert GridView table to Html Table but Rows should be columns and columns should be Rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, .net-3.5, html-table

I have Dataset ds filled up with values  Until now I was displaying values in GridView. Now I want that all the **rows should be columns and columns should be rows**.

I have 2 options: Either **1** I can directly convert grid to columns and display it, or
**2** I can convert the GridView to html and then write loops to convert. I was trying the 2nd option but I cant figure out how I should do that.  Below is my code:

```
For Each dr In dt.Rows
    htmlTable = htmlTable + "<TR>"
    For Each dc In dt.Columns
        htmlTable = htmlTable + "<TD>" + ds.Tables(0).Columns(j).ToString() + ""
        j = j + 1
    Next
    i = i + 1
Next
```

With this code I am still getting same as GridView.  Please help me for converting rows to columns and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your attempting to write an HTML table from the DataTable in the DataSet, flipping rows and columns.  The code you posted has several issues, so I'm using it more as pseudo-code for my answer.

The reason you're getting the same thing (in terms of rows and columns) as the GridView is because you loop through each row, and in each row you loop through all the columns - you're not flipping columns and rows at all.

Try something like this:

```
Dim htmlTable As StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
Dim numberRows As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
Dim numberCols As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1

htmlTable.Append("<table>")

' Loop through each column first
For i As Integer = 0 To numberCols
    htmlTable.Append("<tr>")

    ' Now loop through each row, getting the current columns value
    ' from each row
    For j As Integer = 0 To numberRows
        htmlTable.Append("<td>")
        htmlTable.Append(ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)(i))
        htmlTable.Append("</td>")
    Next

    htmlTable.Append("</tr>")
Next

htmlTable.Append("</table>")

' To get the value of the StringBuilder, call ToString()
Dim resultHtml = htmlTable.ToString()
```

For example, if you have a table like this:

col1    col2    col3

a       b       c

d       e       f

g       h       i

j       k       l

The result would be:

a d g j

b e h k

c f i l

Comment: instead of square brackets [] in ds.tables[0] ... replacing in vb.net  with rounded bracket()

Comment: Yep - you're right. Sorry about that - I deal primarily in C#, so occasionally I slip into that syntax even when it's VB.NET.  I'll edit it for completeness. Good catch.